# Email Bitlocker status from users on an MDM

Tags: powershell, outlook, mdm

So I've been trying to get this script together. So far, the only working part of it is

```
Start-Transcript
Get-Date
manage-bde -status c:
Stop-Transcript
```

I've tried getting the email part of the script to work, using multiple ones I've made and some on the web. However they either specifically require an email SENDER to be listed in the script (I figured maybe I could do something to just read the credentials? But we don't want users to have to press anything.).

I also tried using one to connect to Exchange, and manage/send an email with the log file attached. However, I couldn't get that to work either, was denied access.

Does anyone have an idea on what I can do? I come from Python and have a general idea of Powershell but have barely dug into it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT* - I need to deploy this on Intune in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: What code regarding sending emails have you already tried?

Comment: Sending email can add some complexity. The sending email domain has to allow what you are trying to do, i.e. obeying SPF records. The receiving mail domain has to be configured also with the proper DNS settings and MX records unless mail flow happens without going out to the Internet. Send-MailMessage is an easy way to send email provided you don't violate any domain rules.

Comment: Okay so I found a more effective method. I'm simply having the logfile post to a Shared Folder in Citrix. However, I need get the file to post to the specific path and have a new name for each, that way the command doesn't fail or attempt to overwrite it.